# Confusion about the definition of lower semi-continuity

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, definition

I'm reading the definition of Semi-continuity from Barbu's textbook *Convexity and Optimization in Banach Spaces*. I have seen so far the definition of l.s.c. by the inequality
$$
f\left(x_{0}\right) \le \liminf _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)  := \sup _{V \in \mathscr{V}\left(x_{0}\right)} \inf _{s \in V \setminus \{x_0\}} f(s) , \quad x \in X.
$$

However, the author uses the equality here. The difference comes from different definitions of $\liminf$. I hardly see that they are equivalent. Could you elaborate on this difference?

---

Let $X$ be a topological space. The function $f: X \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is called lower-semicontinuous (upper-semicontinuous) at $x_{0}$ if
$$
f\left(x_{0}\right) \color{blue}{=} \liminf _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) \quad \left(f\left(x_{0}\right)=\limsup _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x)\right)
$$
We recall that
$$
\liminf _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) \color{blue}{=} \sup _{V \in \mathscr{V} \left(x_{0}\right)} \inf _{s \in V} f(s)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\limsup _{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) \color{blue}{=} \inf _{V \in \mathscr{V}\left(x_{0}\right)} \sup _{s \in V} f(s),
$$
where $\mathscr{V}\left(x_{0}\right)$ is a base of neighborhoods of $x_{0}$ in $X$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse inequality holds for any function.

If $V \in \mathscr{V}\left(x_{0}\right)$ then $\inf_{s \in V}f(s) \leq  f(x_0)$. It follows that $$
\sup_{V \in \mathscr{V}\left(x_{0}\right)} \inf_{s \in V}f(s) \leq  f(x_0).$$